# Getting all products with sql

Tags: catalog, sql, products, ce-1.8.1.0

I'm trying to learn magento but I have to finish the project that I'm working on as fast as I  can. So I'm stuck in somewhere. Then I decided to use pure sql. (I know it's really messy)

So is anynone know how can I get all products with sql? I researched database but can't find.

I need product name, thumbnail, price, rating, reviews count and attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it clean!

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addStoreFilter()
    ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    // build your JSON here
}
```

Comment: How can I connect database with this code? I need json data. Do I need include any file?

Comment: See edit. The file have to be placed in Magento root dir.

Comment: echo $collection seems empty.

Comment: What about `echo $collection->getSize();`?

Comment: It's return 1 (There is one product)

Comment: Then everything is fine. Just build your JSON object inside of the loop.

Comment: How can I see which data $collection has?

Comment: Inside of the loop refer to `$product->getName()`, `$product->getPrice()` etc.

Comment: It worked very well, but I cant add product attribute. I set some attributes like color, roomType. How can I filter with these?

Comment: ->addAttributeToFilter('color', 7) was my answer. Thank you for everything!